# Burning Ubuntu 12.04.3 in to DVD errors?

Tags: 12.04, dvd

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.3.
It said a couple errors and then said it finished and ejected DVD after it hit 100%. When I try to view properties of DVD to see if it even had anything on it and it says that the DVD has 0 bytes on used/free space.

I'm new to this so if this is how it should be then sorry.

But any help would be appreciated because I don't wanna boot into a bad burnt DVD.

Also burning DVD too approximately 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure, boot from the DVD, and when you see the logo, press a key, select a language, and select the option where you can check the CD's integrity.

If you cannot boot from the DVD or if the check results in an error, [check the .iso file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and try creating a new USB burning on minimum speed.

Comment: I am completely new to this so sorry for my idiocy but if i try booting into dvd and it fails will it in any way mess up my computer? I do my schooling online so if my computer messes up im screwed lol

Comment: before installing try the option "try ubuntu" from that disk, i think if it is burned properly you can try it without any problems, then you can safely install it.

Comment: Im not going to install it just try it out. This is technically my moms computer and till i get my own i cant change it lol she just now figured out how to work vista. But when i go to the bootmenu via F12 while booting/prompted and i say boot from cd/dvd and the dvd is a bad burn...will it mess up the computer? Like iv said numerous times im new to the computer side of this im more tech savvy on androids.

Comment: @user227983 Good question: your computer isn't at risk if the DVD isn't properly burnt, but you want to be careful if you do hard disk partitioning operations or system installations and take proper measures to ensure that nothing bad is likely to happen: plug in laptops, make sure you run in failsafe X mode if you have a graphics card that may freeze or isn't well supported, and most importantly *always* keep a backup of your important data no matter how dangerous the task you're doing is.

Comment: Lol thanks for the reply. Ill just wait till i get my own laptop and worry bout it then. Theres just too much on this dinosaur. Lol personally i hate windows8 so ill just get me a nice lil laptop and instantly do Ubuntu cuz either way ill have to learn a new OS so why not do Linux instead right?

Answer (score 0):

The DVD was burned as being mastered/finalized (also known as single-session). Reporting the remaining space as 0 bytes is Windows's way of letting you know that you can't add, remove, or edit the files on the disc because it was finalized. When burning install discs, making the CD/DVD like this or not doesn't make a difference.

The few errors, however, could probably mean an actually serious issue (the DVD wasn't **burned correctly**)!

Comment: So...basically i need to find me another blank dvd and try again since this disk is finalized as you put it

Comment: Unfortunately you can't format a finalized disc clean (ugh). I'd say try again with a different DVD. If you get any errors this time try to catch the error message

Comment: I wont be at my house till this weekend and only grabbed 1disk :( i seen the errors but it said finished but some things (like rooting androids) pops error codes but still works so i closed it without thinking.

Comment: If you have the ISO, try running a program that checks the DVD and see if its checksum matches with the ISO. If the checksums match, the DVD is fine.

Comment: Sorry im not the most skilled at computers just droids. Thats why i was gonna try Linux on my dinosaur vista laptop. So idk what to do on that but i got the iso from Ubuntu website and its 707mb and on my flash drive